# Pad list of arrays with zeros in order all arrays to have the same size

Tags: python, numpy

I have created this  array(or I think its a list)  that consist of many arrays that are different size   and that is the reason I put dtype = object .

```
m = [data[a:b] for a, b in zip(z[0:-1:2], z[1:-1:2])]


array = np.array(m, dtype=object)
```

I need to pad each array with zero so that they have the same size (lets say size=smax) and become a "proper" array. My definitions are a little off and I am  sorry in advance

Comment: Can I assume that "data" is a data frame from Pandas? And also, what is "z"?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add extra code cause I wanted to keep it sort. Yes it's a data frame from pandas and z is an 1d array of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) on each row. For example:

```python
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(10)
z = [0, 2, 1, 4, 6, 10, 8, 9]
m = [data[a:b] for a, b in zip(z[0:-1:2], z[1:-1:2])]

max_length = max(len(row) for row in m)
result = np.array([np.pad(row, (0, max_length-len(row))) for row in m])

print(result)
# [[0 1 0 0]
#  [1 2 3 0]
#  [6 7 8 9]]
```

Comment: I am getting this error.   m = [data[a:b] for a, b in zip(z[0:-1:2], z[1:-1:2])]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: If `z` is not an array of integers, you'll have to first convert it to integer type.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification its works as intended